# Menu not showing up when i run emulator

Tags: java, android

My menu is not showing up. Code and screenshot attached.

[image]

```
package com.lmc.mytoolbar_a174476;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R. id. toolbar_main);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//        ActionBar myActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
 //       myActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this related to Javascript?

Comment: [tag:javascript] removed. No sense confusing JavaScript developers by attracting them to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your Toolbar's ThemeOverlay